# using something other than a array to instantiate new object

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I'm a student trying to build a program that captures information of a complex. There is a base class and 2 classes inheriting from the base class(MultiUnits and SingleFamily).  I've got this program that works with values pre load but I want to be able to also enter data from the user.  how can I change the size of the array as the program runs or how can I use a list to store the same data.

I have tried storing the data in a list and it works but when i run a for each loop on it i get the following error:

> CS1579    foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
> 'SingleFamily' because 'SingleFamily' does not contain a public
> instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
public partial class HousingPresentationGUI : Form
{
    SingleFamily[] privateHome;
    MultiUnits[] multi;
    public HousingPresentationGUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HousingPresentationGUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        privateHome = new SingleFamily[5];

        privateHome[0] = new SingleFamily("34 Winston Street", 3, 2, 900.00m);
        privateHome[1] = new SingleFamily("5234 Carolina Ave", 2, 2, 850.00m);
        privateHome[2] = new SingleFamily("54 Magnolia Court", 4, 2, 1150.00m);
        privateHome[3] = new SingleFamily("6910 Reiley", 3, 2, 1000.00m);
        privateHome[4] = new SingleFamily("76 St. Johns Ct.", 3, 2, 1000.00m);

        foreach (SingleFamily homes in privateHome)
        {
            lstBxSingle.Items.Add(homes.Address);
        }


        multi = new MultiUnits[2];

        multi[0] = new MultiUnits("8674 Victoria Lane", 2, 750.00m);
        multi[1] = new MultiUnits("9724 Bridge Street", 2, 700.00m);


        foreach (MultiUnits duplex in multi)
        {
            lstBxMulti.Items.Add(duplex.Address);
        }

    }

    private void cmboTypeOfRental_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblRentalDetails.Text = "";

        lblInstructions.Visible = true;
        if (cmboTypeOfRental.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            lstBxSingle.Visible = true;
            lstBxMulti.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lstBxSingle.Visible = false;
            lstBxMulti.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    private void lstBxMulti_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MultiUnits duplex in multi)
        {
            if (duplex.Address == lstBxMulti.SelectedItem.ToString())
                lblRentalDetails.Text = duplex.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void lstBxSingle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (SingleFamily home in privateHome)
        {
            if (home.Address == lstBxSingle.SelectedItem.ToString())
                lblRentalDetails.Text = home.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your problem isn't arrays or lists its that your treating SingleFamily as if it implements `IEnumerable` and its doesn't

Comment: Instead of SingleFamily[] use List<SingleFamily> and isntead of MultiUnits[] use List<MultiUnits>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of SingleFamily[] use List and isntead of MultiUnits[] use List

```
public partial class HousingPresentationGUI : Form
{
    List<SingleFamily> privateHome = new List<SingleFamily>();
    List<MultiUnits> multi= new List<MultiUnits>();

    public HousingPresentationGUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HousingPresentationGUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        privateHome.Add(new SingleFamily("34 Winston Street", 3, 2, 900.00m));
        ....etc etc add the other private homes

        foreach (SingleFamily homes in privateHome)
        {
            lstBxSingle.Items.Add(homes.Address);
        }

        multi.Add(new MultiUnits("8674 Victoria Lane", 2, 750.00m));
        multi.Add(new MultiUnits("9724 Bridge Street", 2, 700.00m));

        foreach (MultiUnits duplex in multi)
        {
            lstBxMulti.Items.Add(duplex.Address);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: error in your example, you have changed multi to a list but left the array functionality unchanged

Comment: @MikeT I know, i changed the first part to show him, the second part with multi he can edit on his own.

Comment: @MikeT changed it now

Comment: @Wet_pantz thank you so so much been stuck on this for 5 hours, thank you